# how do i protect my ip adress from another users

Tags: wireless-router, ip, cmd.exe, tracking

well I have noticed that its easy to see were to locate someone's ip address or " the router" is there any possible way to hide your ip address and how ?
secondly how can a person show all info by using the cmd ?
thank you

Comment: What IP adress do you want to hide? Your local (like 192.168.1.1) or the adress of your external IP adress which was assigned (like 151.101.129.69)?

Comment: If your router supports `telnet` you can use this to obtain information from the command line, but how complete it will be depends on the `telnet` commands offered.

Comment: Your ip address cannot be used to identify you.  So why are you trying to protect it?

Comment: You cannot hide your public IP address. If you did then the internet would not work as it would not know where to send the data you asked for ...

Comment: What do mean by "show all info"?

Comment: If you mean the computer name was listed in 'router' or queried by command , you may try to disable netbios for your computer . If you mean the MAC address (it might be noted down by someone to identify which computer is used by whom) .Generally network administrator will do this ,if  it is the case , it is not recommended to change MAC address .

Comment: I think we're being a bit harsh on the OP here - the question may not be clear, but that's because the comprehension of the potential 'threat' is a reinforced meme, rather than a technical enquiry. I work helpline for an online MMORPG & this is a common fear; that the user may be "tracked home" by a bad actor.